# Django - Problem with Implementing Models and Views in My PhoneReview Application

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am a beginner in Django. I am building a Django app, named PhoneReview. It will store reviews related to the latest mobile phone. It will also display phone brands, along with the associated phone models. I have already created models for:

1. Brand – details on brand, such as, name, origin, manufacturing since, etc
2. Model – details on model, such as, model name, launch date, platform, etc
3. Review – review article on the mobile phone and date published, etc
4. Many-to-many relationship between Review and Model.

Now, I have to create views for the following:

a. An index page that display all Brands available for mobile phone in the
database

b. A phone model page that display model when a brand is selected.

c. A detail page when a model is selected that contain reviews and newslink

I have managed to create view for **"a. An index page that display all Brands available for mobile phone in the database."** However, I am stuck with **"b. A phone model page that display model when a brand is selected."**

I have managed to display the phone model page. However, the name of the phone model is not being displayed. So, I feel that there is a problem with either the views or templates. But I don't get any error while running the server. So, I am a bit confused.

Here are the codes of **models.py** of the **PhoneReview** app.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturing_since = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand_name

class PhoneModel(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    launch_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_name

class Review(models.Model):
    phone_model = models.ManyToManyField(PhoneModel, related_name='reviews')
    review_article = models.TextField()
    date_published = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.review_article
```

Here are the codes of **urls.py** of the **PhoneReview** app:

```py
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('index', views.BrandListView.as_view(), name='brandlist'),
    path('phonemodel/<int:pk>/', views.ModelView.as_view(), name='modellist'),
]
```

Here are the codes of **views.py** of the **PhoneReview** app:

```py
from django.views import generic
from .models import Brand, PhoneModel


class BrandListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/brandlist.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_brands'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Brand.objects.all()


class ModelView(generic.DetailView):
    model = PhoneModel
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/phonemodel.html'
```

Here are the codes of **base.html** file. As the name suggests, this is the base page. It will be extended for being used by the other pages, like **brandlist.html** for showing phone brand list and **phonemodel.html** for showing phone models. It is located inside templates > GameReview folder:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>{% block title %}  {% endblock %}</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }

    /* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */
    footer {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 25px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Phone Radar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">#</li>
        <li><a href="#">Add Phone</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Add Review</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container text-left">
   {% block content %}  {% endblock %}
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here are the codes of **brandlist.html** file, which displays the list of the phone brands. It located inside templates > GameReview folder. I have managed to display the phone brands at http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.

```html
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title%}
Brand List
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!--Page content-->
<h1>This is Brand List Page</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for brand in all_brands %}
            <li>{{ brand.brand_name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
<img src="{% static "images/brandlist.jpg" %}" alt="Super Mario Odyssey" /> <!-- New line -->
{% endblock %}
```

Here are the codes of **phonemodel.html** file, which is supposed to display the phone brands. However, I can't display the output of `{{ phonemodel.model_name }}` at http://127.0.0.1:8000/phonemodel/1/. It just shows the H1 heading. The file is located inside templates > GameReview folder.

```html
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title%}
Phone Model Page
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!--Page content-->
<h1>This is Phone Model Page</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for phonemodel in all_phonemodel %}
            <li>{{ phonemodel.model_name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
<img src="{% static "images/brandlist.jpg" %}" alt="Super Mario Odyssey" /> <!-- New line -->
{% endblock %}
```

I am stuck here. The **phonemodel.html** is supposed to display the phone brands. However, I can't display the output of `{{ phonemodel.model_name }}` at http://127.0.0.1:8000/phonemodel/1/. It just shows the H1 heading. There are no errors showing. I tried several hours to fix it. But being a Django beginner, I am facing a hard time fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phonemodel template is totally wrong. Not only do you not have anything called `all_phonemodel` in the template context, even if you did it wouldn't be iterable because this is a *detail* view, not a list view.

Remove the loop and just access `object`:

```
<ul>
    <li>{{ object.model_name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your "class ModelView":

```
context_object_name = 'all_phonemodel'

def get_queryset(self):
        return PhoneModel.objects.all()
```